# What's wrong with this .vimrc - I'm not getting the colors I'm supposed to

Tags: vim, colors

What's wrong with this .vimrc? The statusline remains uncolored. This isn't my color config, but it's supposed to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IkNj.jpg). The configuration is otherwise working as intended.

```
hi User1 guifg=#ffdad8  guibg=#880c0e
hi User2 guifg=#000000  guibg=#F4905C
hi User3 guifg=#292b00  guibg=#f4f597
hi User4 guifg=#112605  guibg=#aefe7B
hi User5 guifg=#051d00  guibg=#7dcc7d
hi User7 guifg=#ffffff  guibg=#880c0e gui=bold
hi User8 guifg=#ffffff  guibg=#5b7fbb
hi User9 guifg=#ffffff  guibg=#810085
hi User0 guifg=#ffffff  guibg=#094afe
nnoremap <C-Tab> :bn<CR>
nnoremap <C-S-Tab> :bp<CR>
nmap <F7> :tabprevious<CR>
nmap <F8> :tabnext<CR>
nmap <S-Å> :earlier<CR> 
nmap <S-h>  :tabnext<CR>
nmap <S-l>  :tabnext<CR>
nmap gn :tabnew<CR>
set title
set wildmenu
set titleold=""
set titlestring=VIM:\ %F
set number
set backup " backup on
set backupdir=~/.backup
set directory=~/.backup
set noruler
set laststatus=2
set statusline=%t
set statusline=
set statusline+=%7*\[%n]                                  "buffernr
set statusline+=%1*\ %<%F\                                "File+path
set statusline+=%2*\ %y\                                  "FileType
set statusline+=%3*\ %{''.(&fenc!=''?&fenc:&enc).''}      "Encoding
set statusline+=%3*\ %{(&bomb?\",BOM\":\"\")}\            "Encoding2
set statusline+=%4*\ %{&ff}\                              "FileFormat (dos/unix..) 
set statusline+=%5*\ %{&spelllang}\%{HighlightSearch()}\  "Spellanguage & Highlight on?
set statusline+=%8*\ %=\ row:%l/%L\ (%03p%%)\             "Rownumber/total (%) set statusline+=%9*\ col:%03c\                            "Colnr
set statusline+=%0*\ \ %m%r%w\ %P\ \                      "Modified? Readonly? Top/bot.
function! HighlightSearch()
  if &hls
    return 'H'
  else  
    return ''
  endif 
endfunction
~                                                                              
~
```

Comment: What do you get instead of the desired look?

Comment: have you tested in gvim? those colors will only show in gvim. I tested with your config, I got the expected colors in my gvim, even though I don't like so colorful status line.

Comment: Do you set a color scheme anywhere? That would clear out all your highlight commands, setting them to default values or the value in the color scheme.

Answer (score 0):

This should work in GVIM, but in the terminal, there will be *no* colors, because you didn't define any:

```
hi User1 guifg=#ffdad8  guibg=#880c0e
```

Note that you've just used `guifg` and `guibg`; for color-capable terminals, you additionally need to define `ctermfg` / `ctermbg` (but you cannot use the full RGB spectrum, just 16 named or 256 indexed colors, depending on the value of `:set t_Co?`).

---

Plugins like [CSApprox](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2390) can take the GUI color definitions and convert them to a closely matching 256-color `cterm` color palette for high-color terminals. This helps with colorschemes that otherwise only pick from the bland default 16-color terminal color palette, or only provide GUI color definitions.

Another approach is taken by [csexact](https://github.com/KevinGoodsell/vim-csexact), which modifies the (supported) terminal's palette to exactly match Vim's GUI colors.